# Outlook Add-Ins - Limits of Javascript API

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a working Outlook Add-in with type MessageComposeCommandSurface that uses Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async to insert file attachments from an external system.

I understand that addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async is limited to files of 25 MB.

The API method Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync does not have these size constraints, but requires a URI parameter which seems impractical for my purposes.

I've tried code like

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                
let startIndex = url.indexOf("blob:");
let cleanBlob = url.substr(startIndex + 5);         
                
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(     
                    cleanBlob, ...
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way for me to get around the size restrictions without using a publicly accessible URI for addFileAttachmentAsync, or am I using that method incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

addFileAttachmentAsync doesn't take a url like a blob.

It takes in an actual URL, so your function call should look like:

Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://contso.com/myfile.png", "myfile.png");

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, I understand it takes a URL.  Please see the original question. 
 I need to attach files from my external application which can be stored in a file server or database.

Comment: The only other fileAttachment function that is close is addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async. If you can get the file you need into base64 format to your add-in, you can attach it with that.